# nginx config try_file with a conditional rewrite based on if a target file exists

Tags: nginx

I am using a setup as shown below to redirect all unfound files to single fallback location

```
  location / {
      try_files $uri @missing;
  }

  location @missing {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /fallback.php last;
  }
```

This is working well, but I now have a more complex requirement in that I effectively need a fallback to my fallback.

So - I need to extend this so that if fallback.php does not exist it would rewrite to fallback2.php

UPDATE:

Here is the rest of my config file written with the try_files line as suggested by suggested by @AD7six in the comments, just in case there is a problem in the php handler:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>\w*?)?\.?(?<domain>\w+\.\w+)$;

    if ($subdomain = "") {
            set $subdomain "www";
    }

    if (!-d "/home/me/projects/$domain/$subdomain") {
            set $subdomain "www";
    }

    root /home/me/projects/$domain/$subdomain;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            try_files $uri /fallback.php /fallback2.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

if I just have one location in the  try_files line it works:

```
try_files $uri /fallback.php;
```

but when I a second location it stats downloading fallback.php html instead of redirecting

```
try_files $uri /fallback.php /fallback2.php;
```

Comment: in what way does `try_files $uri /fallback.php /fallback2.php;` not do what you want?

Comment: @AD7six that was my first attempt, but for some reason this just resulted in fallback.php content being downloaded instead of re-directing.

Comment: @AD7six  try_files $uri /fallback.php; works and displays the php files correctly, as does visiting fallback.php of fallback.php directly.  The issue is that when I add /fallback2.php to the try_files line (as in your first examples) thats when it stats downloading the html content of fallback.php.

Comment: Intersting regarding try files. Is this a development setup? Looks pretty inappropriate for production.

Comment: @AD7six yes this is a development environment.

Answer (score 1):

```
location = /fallback.php {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

Note: if you have regexped-locations for *.php, they will be in priority.